# Como interceptar jQuery DataTables usando Ajax Encadeado

Tags: jquery-datatables

Eu estou escrevendo um código que, entre outras coisas, precisa interceptar O **ajax** de um **datatable** e adicionar algum dado.

Assim:

```
$("#table").DataTable{
    ajax: {
      data: ...
    }).MyPlugin();

//In another file: plugin code
$.fn.DataTable.Api.register('MyPlugin()', function (params) {

    //something like
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {

    var paramsDataTableAjax = $.deparam(options.data);

    paramsDataTableAjax["additionalFields"].push({ "Key": DADO_ADICIONAL, "Value": "" });

    options.data = $.param(paramsDataTableAjax);
    });

    //more code ...
    });
});
```

Eu não consigo descobrir como fazer isso usando o "plugin" que eu criei (MyPlugin()).

Comment: Perdão, me distrai. Ia deleta-la mas o Diego se deu ao trabalho, então: obrigado Diego.

Comment: De nada. Mas mesmo assim precisamos de mais explicações. O que você precisa ? O processo da sua rotina...

Comment: @DiegoSouza acho que houve confusão na tradução. Editei. Adicionei também a variável "DADO_ADICIONAL", que é o que quero acrescentar ao "data" da chamada Ajax. O que não ficou claro?